# TFS 2015 >> Exporting Test Cases and associated detail Steps in excel

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We can import the test cases with their associated steps from excel to TFS.

Is there any way or tool for exporting the test cases with their associated detail steps into excel?

Currently i am using TFS 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can query the test case work items and select Steps Column in VS, then export the query to Excel directly. But you need to reorganize the format of the Steps:

[image]

2. You can export test artifacts data on TFS Web Access so that they can either be sent via email or printed. The Export capability allows you to customize what data you want to export. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380763.aspx

> For exporting to Excel, you can choose the Print or Email option from
>   the Export dialog box, then choose Cancel from the Print dialog box.
>   The data for the report is displayed. Select the test cases and
>   associated steps, then you can copy and paste it into a Excel if you
>   want. All the formatting in the report is retained.